# Solid Region of Infinitely Many Type-I Regions

Tags: calculus

Find a solid region in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which can be written as disjoint union of countably infinitely many type-I regions, but cannot be written as disjoint union of finitely many type-I regions. If such region does not exist, prove it.

Type-I regions are defined as:  region where $u_{1}(x,y)\le z \le u_{2}(x,y)$
and where $(x,y)$ are in $D$, which spans the $xy$-plane.

Comment: What are $u_1, u_2?$  What is $D?$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/). Please, try to make the title of your question more informative.

Answer (score 1):

The $u_{1}(x,y)$ and $u_{2}(x,y)$ represent two continuous functions.  From Stewart Calculus 7th edition on page 1018:

"A solid region $E$ is said to be of **type 1** if it lies between the graphs of two continuous functions of $x$ and $y$, that is,

$$E= \big\{ (x,y,z) \; | \;(x,y) \in D, \; u_{1}(x,y) ≤ z ≤ u_{2}(x,y) \big \} $$

where $D$ is the projection of $E$ onto the $xy$-plane."